# How to use OOB report widget as embedded servicenow

Tags: widget, report, servicenow

For simple listing OOB (out of the box) widget, I can able to write code like this:

HTML:

```
<widget id="widget-simple-list" options="data.approvalsOption" ></widget>
```

Server script:

```
    data.approvalsOption = {
        "secondary_fields":"u_incident_title",
        "always_show":"true",
        "table":"incident",
        "filter":"",
        "display_field":"number",
        "maximum_entries":"5"
    };
```

In a similar way, I want to add an embedded report widget, I tried something like this:

HTML inside another widget:

```
<widget id="report" options="data.reportData" ></widget>
```

Server script:

```
data.reportData = {
    "report_id":"45ytrhg43trgfgerewrfdads"  //My report sys_id
};
```

I am able to achieve this with page designer and Edit->select_report (but I want as the embedded widget)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

HTML inside another widget:

```html
<sp-widget widget="c.data.embeddedReport"></sp-widget>
```

Server Script

```html
    var reportOptions = {
        report_id: "45ytrhg43trgfgerewrfdads",  // Report sys_id
        widget_parameters: '{"report_id":{"displayValue":"Report Title" }}'
    };
    
data.embeddedReport = $sp.getWidget("report", reportOptions);
```